# How to account for number of electrodes in EEG data while converting to frequency domain?

Tags: matlab, python, eeg

I have raw data from 64 electrode EEG in CSV format where there are multiple rows and 64 columns. I am using the following Python code to separate the data into frequency bands:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Sampling rate = 500 Hz
fs = 500

# Define EEG bands
eeg_bands = {'Delta':  (0, 4),
             'Theta':  (4, 8),
             'Alpha':  (8, 14),
             'Beta':   (14, 30),
             'Gamma':  (30, 45)}

f = open('output-stddev.csv', 'w', newline='')
w = csv.DictWriter(f, eeg_bands.keys())

data = np.genfromtxt('rawCSV.csv', delimiter=',')

# Get real amplitudes of FFT (only in postive frequencies)
fft_vals = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(data))

# Get frequencies for amplitudes in Hz
fft_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(data), 1.0/fs)

# Take the mean of the fft amplitude for each EEG band
eeg_band_fft = dict()
for band in eeg_bands:
    freq_ix = np.where((fft_freq >= eeg_bands[band][0]) &
                       (fft_freq < eeg_bands[band][1]))[0]
    eeg_band_fft[band] = np.std(fft_vals[freq_ix])

w.writerow(eeg_band_fft)
f.close()
```

I believe the code is not correctly thought-out because it doesn't account for the fact that there are 64 electrodes anywhere in it. How do I accurately convert raw EEG data from all the electrodes to the frequency domain?

Comment: In what sense? What would the ideal output look like?

Comment: I wound not say that the code is incorrect, the code is more than correct, the question is if you apply it correctly, and here the answer is no. So what you should do is either loop over your electrodes or adapt the code that it handles matrices and not vectors ...

Comment: Welcome to DSP! It would also be helpful if you could provide a snippet of the data from `rawCSV.csv`. Without any real data it's impossible to fully asses the code.